# create-react-app doesn't generate public and src folders thus cannot get started

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npm-start

i have installed CRA for over a month and have been working with it without having any problems, however today i created a new react app and it builds the folders and directories except it doesn't generate  src and public folder(it just generated node-modules folder) thus when i run npm start it gives me an error saying:

```
npm ERR! missing script: start
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initially you might have installed create-react-app globally.Try to remove using  `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` command and then try `npx create-react-app <your-app-name>`.
The reason is, npx should use it's latest version to work. Hope your doubt is now cleared

Comment: this solution works for the above problem. do you face the similar problem where the folder gets built but doesn't generate `src` . if so try checking your “build” script in package.json .

Comment: No It geenearets but src and public folder are missing

Answer (score 2):

I still have no idea what was the reason but I got it working doing these:

-uninstalled `create-react-app`using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`.

-using `npx create-react-app app-name` I created a new app and now it's working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried installing in different computers and for most cases the above codes helped to fix the issue. But in a rare case I had to use another code and it worked perfectly. Try running the below code

```
 npx --ignore-existing create-react-app Your-AppName
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the suggestions stated above but none works for me.I just run these commands and create a new project.

1. `npm rm -g create-react-app`
2. `npm install -g create-react-app`
3. `npx create-react-app@latest my-app`

This work for me.

Answer (score -3):

You can create project with **yarn**:

```
yarn create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: worth to mention that it would require yarn to be installed

Comment: Doesn't answer the question and yarn probably has the same problem