# why src and public folders missing in react creat app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules, create-react-app, npx

I am trying to create create app using npx create-react-app my-app

I have npm 6.13

and node : 12.14.1

I tired to  follow the soultion in [create-react-app doesn't generate public and src folders thus cannot get started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59234987/create-react-app-doesnt-generate-public-and-src-folders-thus-cannot-get-started)

but it is not working ?

Any chance ?

Comment: try creating the project with `npx create-react-app project_name`

Answer (score 0):

You might have already installed create-react-app globally. but npx always uses the latest version of create-react-app. please check the create-react-app version by

```
create-react-app -v
```

and ensure its latest by checking [Changelog.md](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). if not try uninstalling the global package by

```
sudo npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

make sure you have uninstalled globally and then try running

```
npx create-react-app <project_name>
```

Comment: this is the same soultion described in the answer in the question

Comment: It sloved it was antivirus issue

Answer (score 0):

initially tried using but not worked: `npm rm -g create-react-app`, `npm install -g create-react-app`, `npx create-react-app <your-app-name>`.

below command works : `npx --ignore-existing create-react-app <Your-AppName>`

Comment: no longer does anything:
npx: the --ignore-existing argument has been removed.